# How to add query, filter params in axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, apisauce

```
http://localhost:9000/api/res.users?sudo=1&filter=[["id","=",11]]&query={id,name,image_128,phone}
```

how to compose above url with axios and send it to server.

i tried params but i think i'm missing something because i'm getting

```
     Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

my code looks like this[this was when i tried using apisauce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5UiO.png)

now using axios i tried this way

```
const res = axios.get('http://localhost:9000/api/res.users', {
        params:{
            sudo: '1',
            filter: '[["id", "=", 11]]',
            query: "{phone,name}"
        }
    });
    console.log("res", res);
```

Comment: You are logging an unresolved promise, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function for async operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9000/api/res.users', {
    params:{
        sudo: '1',
        filter: '[["id", "=", 11]]',
        query: "{phone,name}"
    }
}).then(res=>{
   console.log("res", res);
});
```